# WebCam is recognized but only with low resolution?

Tags: ubuntu, drivers, webcam

My ultimate goal is to capture video with OpenCV from a WebCam in high resolution. However, the webcam that I have connected to my laptop via USB is detected but does only provide standard VGA resolution (640x480), even though it has technically the capability to capture video with FullHD (1920×1080) at 30 fps.

I assume, that the driver that Ubuntu is using by default in order to access my WebCam (ov519) is not capable of using the WebCam's full potential.

My question is how can one find and install an appropriate driver for an external WebCam using Ubuntu?

---

#### Technical Details:

The `lsusb` output is:

```
Bus 002 Device 008: ID 05a9:4519 OmniVision Technologies, Inc. Webcam Classic
```

And `v4l2-ctl -d /dev/video1 --all` output is:

```
Driver Info (not using libv4l2):
    Driver name   : ov519
    Card type     : USB Camera
    Bus info      : usb-0000:00:14.0-3
    Driver version: 4.15.18
    Capabilities  : 0x85200001
        Video Capture
        Read/Write
        Streaming
        Extended Pix Format
        Device Capabilities
    Device Caps   : 0x05200001
        Video Capture
        Read/Write
        Streaming
        Extended Pix Format
Priority: 2
Video input : 0 (ov519: ok)
Format Video Capture:
    Width/Height      : 640/480
    Pixel Format      : 'JPEG'
    Field             : None
    Bytes per Line    : 640
    Size Image        : 115790
    Colorspace        : JPEG
    Transfer Function : Default (maps to sRGB)
    YCbCr/HSV Encoding: Default (maps to ITU-R 601)
    Quantization      : Default (maps to Full Range)
    Flags             : 
Streaming Parameters Video Capture:
    Frames per second: invalid (0/0)
    Read buffers     : 2
```

Answer (score 0):

Information from this site that compiles info on OmniVision (OVCam) cameras: http://ovcam.org/ov511/cameras.html

| Manufacturer | Model (yellow=USB 2.0) | ID# | Bridge | Sensor | Linux Status (bold means I own one) |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| OmniVision | OV519/OV8610 Eval Board | N/A | OV519 | OV8600/OV8610, built-in microphone? | Works with ov51x driver |

Download Page I downloaded and checked myself, at VirusTotal, both Stable Drivers)

Download Page: http://ovcam.org/ov511/download.html#ov51x

| Version | Date | 2.2 Kernels | 2.4 Kernels | 2.5/2.6 Kernels | Downloads | Stable? |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1.65-1.11-mark | 2004/08/21 | 2.2.18 - 2.2.26 | 2.4.0 - 2.4.31 | 2.6.0 - 2.6.8 | download (109K) | Yes |

Driver Link: http://ovcam.org/ov511/download/ov51x/ov51x-1.65-1.11-mark.tar.bz2

---

I unpacked `ov51x-1.65-1.10-mark.tar.bz2`.

Extract the drivers into their own folder(s). I used 7Zip.

For Information on Installing Drivers look in the `Doc/` directory. There are PDF and other HTML and a text file inside.

Comment: Yes, I have been there and unfortunately all the links are broken. It seems like http://www.rastageeks.org/ is down and the "JPEG hacked Linux driver" no longer available.

Comment: @Genius Like is said, I don't think you need a driver.  I see your video is set to 1, usually it it video0. Anyway's try this setting:
v4l2-ctl --device=/dev/video1 --set-fmt-video=width=1920,height=1080